# Navigation bar clear color is black

Tags: ios, swift

I have imageView in my view. And I want to make navigation bar clear that I can see my image. But when I use this code I get black color:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Create an image view and add it on NavigationBar. If you set NavigationBar color clear it is going to be Black, it takes UIWindow's color.

Comment: This might be because `UIColor.clear` is black with zero alpha (i.e. 0,0,0,0). Try using the `UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0)` initialiser. This will give 1,1,1,0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this piece of code.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```